Код на telethon не работае на VPS
У меня есть код

from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio
import logging

# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Данные для подключения
api_id = 21*****6
api_hash = '52fda85*********************66'

# Создание клиента с указанными данными
client = TelegramClient('ses', api_id, api_hash)


async def main():
    try:
        # Запускаем клиента
        await client.start()
        logger.info("Клиент успешно запущен.")

        # ID пользователя для отправки сообщения
        user_id = 535541118
        message = "привет"

        # Отправка сообщения
        await client.send_message(user_id, message)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Произошла ошибка: %s", e)

    finally:
        # Отключение клиента
        await client.disconnect()


# Основной блок выполнения
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

При запуске скрипта в pycharm всё работает, но когда запускаю на vps скрипт не работает. Я пытался выводить логами инфу, вот что пишется когда запускаю в pycharm
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull complete!
INFO:__main__:Клиент успешно запущен.
INFO:__main__:Сообщение 'привет' успешно отправлено пользователю с ID 535541118
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnecting from 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnection from 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull complete!

А вот когда на впс
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull complete!

Начало похоже, но вот когда надо выполнять код, ничего не происходит. Кто знает почему, библиотека установлена и там и там, сервер на Ubuntu 20 (Python 3.8.10
), на компе в пайчарм Python 3.12.6
Начало похоже, но вот когда надо выполнять код, ничего не происходит. Кто знает почему, библиотека установлена и там и там, сервер на Ubuntu 20 (Python 3.8.10
), на компе в пайчарм Python 3.12.6

Попробуйте воспроизвести серверное окружение в docker-e локально, и ищите дальше, где разница.

Попробуйте поменять уровень логирования на более подробный

Логирование ничего мне так и не дало. Но я начал изучать вопрос, оказалось есть аналогичная библиотека telethon'у - это Pyrogram, с ним проблем вообще никаких нет

Да и вообще модно современно это aiogram )  Раз уж у вас asyncio всё-равно используется.

Согласен, почти все на aiogram, но я уже разобрался с telethon и просто не перехожу, так как его функционала мне супер хватает для задач
